# Python csv reader can't seek to line

Tags: python, csv, io

I have a simple test CSV file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

I am trying to read the first two lines, seek back one line, and re-read the next line:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    pos = f.tell()
    print 'pos: {0}'.format(pos)
    print reader.next()

    pos = f.tell()
    print 'pos: {0}'.format(pos)
    print reader.next()

    f.seek(pos)
    pos = f.tell()
    print 'pos: {0}'.format(pos)

    print reader.next()
    pos = f.tell()
    print 'pos: {0}'.format(pos)
```

However, the file is being read entirely on the first call to `next()`:

```
pos: 0
['1', '2', '3']
pos: 27
['4', '5', '6']
pos: 27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
StopIteration
```

I tried setting `buffering=0`, but the same problem arises. If I use the file object explicitly to do `readline()`, everything works fine. Is there some way to prevent the csv reader from reading in multiple lines at the first `next()` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The documentation for [`file.next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.next#file.next) explains why:

> **In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the
>   lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a
>   hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead
>   buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline())
>   does not work right.** However, using seek() to reposition the file to
>   an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

In fact, if you use the `io` module to open the file (which is the default in Python 3.x), a specific `IOError` gets raised telling you its not allowed:

```
  File "./c.py", line 12, in <module>
    pos = f.tell()
IOError: telling position disabled by next() call
```